# How to get exact number of array elements(members)in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

Say I have an array like this:

```
array('a string', 23, array(array('key'=>'value'), 67, 'another string'), 'something else')
```

and I want to know **how many values** my array has, **excluding arrays** that are member of the main array. How? (The expected result is **6**)

Foreach loop is not suitable because of the problem itself - **unknown depth of array**.

Does anyone know how to implement this?

Comment: What should be result for your example ?

Comment: Exactly six. Values, arrays as part of main array not included...

Comment: `count($array,COUNT_RECURSIVE);` is show 8. Means Not Correct.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [array_walk_recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php).

```
$count = 0; 
array_walk_recursive($arr, function($var) use (&$count) { 
  $count++; 
}); 
echo $count;
```

***[The working demo.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/rTAyvm)***

Comment: hmmm, for some reason my output is 8, just like count($array,COUNT_RECURSIVE). Let me see what's the problem...

Answer (score 1):

Following function returns the number of all **non-array** values within a given array -- despite it is multidimensional or not.

```
function countNonArrayValues(array $array)
{
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($array as $element) {
        $count += is_array($element) ? countNonArrayValues($element) : 1;
    }
    return $count;
}
```